# how can i call itemclicklistener inside a switch onclicklistener android

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener, uiswitch

i am creating an android application. what i want is that when the user clicked the switch in a row it call the listview's onitemclicklistener. before, i tried to call the listview's itemclicklistener on the switch's onclicklistener inside my customAdapter but it throws an error. if there's no way for me to achieve my desired result, please tell me an alternative way. if you are wondering why do i need the listview's itemclick to be called inside the switch's onclick is because the itemclick is the only way i can get the rows id which i will use for updating the rows.

thank you in advance. :)

here's the code of the activity with the listview:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewForm extends Activity {
    private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
    private TodoItemDatabase td;
    private ListView lv;
    private Switch swi;
    int devId, devPos;
    long devId2;
    String devName;
    int devWatt, devStat;
    //for timer
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    Handler handler, adapter;
    //for bill compute
    int totalWatt;
    int totalHour = 1;
    double wattHourPerDay, kiloWattPerDay, kiloWattPerMonth, billPerMonth; 
    int timerFirstRun;
    double costPerMonth = 8.5568 ;
    //int delay = 3600000;
    int delay = 50000;
    TextView lblBillVal;
    //double costPerMonth = .10 ;
    OnItemClickListener itemClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_form);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_data);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        lblBillVal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblBillValue);
        lblBillVal.setText("");

        swi = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        //itemClick

        itemClick = new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("batelec", "id: "+id+" pos: "+pos);
                TodoItemDatabase td = new TodoItemDatabase(getBaseContext());
                int x = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(id));
                Cursor cur = td.getOneRow(x);
                if(cur != null){
                    if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                        Log.d("batelec", "inside onitemclick, cur count: "+cur.getCount());
                        devStat = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(cur.getColumnName(3)));
                        Log.d("batelec", "1st devStat: "+devStat);
                        if(devStat == 0){
                            devStat = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            devStat = 0;
                        }

                        devId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(cur.getColumnName(0)));
                        devName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cur.getColumnName(1)));
                        devWatt = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(cur.getColumnName(2)));
                        //devStat
                        Log.d("batelec", "2nd devStat: "+devStat);
                        td.updateStat(new TodoItem(devId, devName, devWatt, devStat));

                        CustomCursorAdapter cr = new CustomCursorAdapter(ListViewForm.this, td.getAllData());
                        cr.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        lv.setAdapter(cr);
                    }

                }
            }

        };
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(itemClick);
        //itemLongClick
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id){
                Log.d("batelec", "longclick");

                return onLongListItemClick(v, pos, id);
            }
        });

        td = new TodoItemDatabase(this);
        new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(ListViewForm.this, td.getAllData());
                lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });

        //useHandler();
    }
    //itemLongClick
    protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, final int pos, long id) {
        Log.d("batelec", "onLongListItemClick id= " + id + " position= " + pos);

        devId2 = id;
        devPos = pos;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ListViewForm.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_form_design);
        dialog.setTitle("Option");
        Button btnEdit = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogBtnEdit);
        Button btnDelete = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogBtnDelete);

        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                TodoItemDatabase td = new TodoItemDatabase(ListViewForm.this);
                Cursor cur = td.getAllData();

                if(cur!=null){
                    if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                        cur.moveToPosition(pos);
                        devId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        devName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceName"));
                        devWatt = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceWattage"));
                        devStat = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceStatus"));
                        Log.d("batelec", "devID: "+devId+" devName: "+devName+" devWatt: "+devWatt+" devStat: "+devStat);
                    }
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),AddDeviceForm.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                Log.d("batelec", "sent id: "+devId);
                b.putInt("xtraDevId", devId);
                b.putString("xtraDevName", devName);
                b.putInt("xtraWatt", devWatt);
                b.putInt("xtraStat", devStat);
                Log.d("batelec", "sent devStat: "+devStat);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnDelete = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogBtnDelete);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

                TodoItemDatabase td = new TodoItemDatabase(ListViewForm.this);
                Cursor cur = td.getAllData();

                if(cur!=null){
                    if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                        cur.moveToPosition(pos);
                        devId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        devName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceName"));
                        devWatt = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceWattage"));
                        devStat = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceStatus"));
                        devPos = pos;
                        Log.d("batelec", "devID: "+devId+" devName: "+devName+" devWatt: "+devWatt+" devStat: "+devStat+" devPos: "+devPos);
                    }
                }
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("xtraId", devId);
                b.putInt("xtraPos", devPos);
                DialogFragment deleteDiag = new DeleteDialog();
                deleteDiag.setArguments(b);
                deleteDiag.show(getFragmentManager(), "deleteDevice");
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        Log.d("batelec", "showing dialog");
        return true;
    }

    public void useHandler(){
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
    }
    public void stopRunnable(View v){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            TodoItemDatabase td = new TodoItemDatabase(getBaseContext());
            Cursor cur = td.getActiveDevice();

            if(timerFirstRun == 0){
                timerFirstRun++;
                Log.d("batelec", "timer = 0");
            }
            else{
                try{
                    if(cur != null){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "1 hour elapsed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        /*cur.moveToFirst();
                        for(int x = 1; x <= cur.getCount(); x++){
                            int id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceName"));
                            int watt = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceWattage"));
                            int stat = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("deviceStatus"));
                            Log.d("batelec", "id: " + id + " name: " + name + " watt: " + watt + " status: " + stat);
                            totalWatt = totalWatt + watt;
                            cur.moveToNext();
                        }*/
                        totalWatt = 125;
                        Log.d("batelec", "total hour: "+totalHour);
                        wattHourPerDay = totalWatt * totalHour;//all active device wattage * hours it is active

                        Log.d("batelec", "wattPerHour: "+wattHourPerDay+" (totalWatt * totalHour)");
                        kiloWattPerDay = wattHourPerDay / 1000;//all device watts divided by 1000 watts = 1 kW

                        Log.d("batelec", "kilowatt per day: "+kiloWattPerDay+" (wattPerHour / 1000)");
                        kiloWattPerMonth = (wattHourPerDay * 30) / 1000;//watts per month

                        Log.d("batelec", "kiloWatt per month: "+kiloWattPerMonth+" ((wattPerHour * 30) / 1000)");
                        billPerMonth = kiloWattPerMonth * costPerMonth;//estimated bill per month

                        Log.d("batelec", "bill per month: "+billPerMonth+" (kiloWattPerMonth * costPerMonth)");

                        Double res;
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                        res = Double.valueOf(df.format(billPerMonth));

                        Log.d("batelec", "new bill: "+res);

                        lblBillVal.setText(String.valueOf(res));
                        totalHour++;
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("batelec", ""+e);
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    };

}
```

here's my custom adapter code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    int wattTotal = 0;
    int pos, i;
    int[] tags;
    //components
    TextView txtDevName, txtDevWatt;
    Switch swiStatus;
    //ViewHolder viewHolder;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_design, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        txtDevName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDeviceName);
        txtDevName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1)));

        txtDevWatt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDeviceWatt);
        txtDevWatt.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

        swiStatus = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        int stat = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3)));

        Log.d("batelec", "Name: "+ name + " Stat: "+stat);
        //Log.d("batelec", "tags: "+i);
       /* swiStatus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("batelec", "switch click: "+i);
                ListViewForm lvf = new ListViewForm();
                lvf.itemClick();
            }

        });*/

        if (stat == 0){
            swiStatus.setChecked(false);
        }
        else{
            swiStatus.setChecked(true);
        }
        //i++;


    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to trigger the switch listener? for getting the switch status only right?

Comment: show the xml of the Activity, you can drop the adapter snippet, it useless

Comment: what i want to get is the id and the status. what i want is that the switch is used as a switch and not just a thing for displaying  the status.  also it is more logical if the switch have the way to change the status of the device and not the listview itself.

Answer (score 0):

here's my xml, i don't understand what yshahak meant at first

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.03" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:text="@string/txtDeviceName"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:text="@string/txtDeviceWatt"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.03"
                android:gravity="top|end"
                android:text="@string/txtStatus"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblApproxBill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txtEstimateBill"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblBillValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/txtNull"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:width="@dimen/listNameFieldSize" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```